# How to display the term name used in a custom loop using a tax_query in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to display the 'term name' dynamically based on the term slug used in tax_query.

I need the value Novedades which is the name of the term that has the slug 'novedades', that I use in `'terms' => 'novedades'`.

It should be displayed in the h2 tag. How can I grab that value?

My code:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'cuadros',
        'post_per_page' => 4,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'tipo_de_cuadro',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'novedades'
            ),
        ),
    );
    
    $postQuery = new WP_Query($args);
?>

<?php if ( $postQuery->have_posts()) : ?>

<div class="product-carousel">

     <h2> x x x x x x x x x x x x x x </h2>

     <div class="owl-carousel">

     <?php while( $postQuery->have_posts() ) : $postQuery->the_post(); ?>

         <div class="product-carousel__item">
             <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="">
             <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
             <p class="producr-carousel__precio">desde $595</p>
             <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="producr-carousel__button">Detalles</a>
         </div>
        
     <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    </div>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, but given that you know what the slug is then the easiest way is probably to use the [`get_term_by` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/).

You can use the slug to get all the term details using `get_term_by` including the name. This is separate to your WP_Query , so you can use it outside the loop.

```
<?php
// set up variables for the slug & taxonomy - then this can all be changed dynamically if you need to
$term_slug = "novedades";
$term_taxonomy = "tipo_de_cuadro";

// Pass the slug & taxonomy to get_term_by to get all the term details
$term = get_term_by('slug', $term_slug, $term_taxonomy); 
$term_name = $term->name;    // get the name from the term

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'cuadros',
    'post_per_page' => 4,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $term_taxonomy,
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $term_slug
        ),
    ),
);

$postQuery = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $postQuery->have_posts()) : ?>

    <div class="product-carousel">

        <!-- you can use your term_name variable here  before you set the_post -->
        <h2><?php echo $term_name; ?></h2>
        <!-- [do stuff....] -->
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Glad it worked! If you mark the answer as accepted, it will show your question is answered and also highlight to other users with similar problems that this might work for them too :)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I already accept the answer. Have a great day.